# Orbeon Form Runner Wizard current page number

Tags: orbeon

Is there a way to get the current page number (and the total number of pages) when in wizard view? Have had a look at https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/wizard/wizard.xbl, but it all looked pretty internal.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the page number? I am thinking that it would be good if there was a way to display it as a step number, whether on the table of contents or otherwise.

Comment: We are planning on both displaying it (though we may be able to use the inbuilt wizard TOC for our requirements) and implementing a save on next/prev (to a web service), for which we want to be able to include the current page number. Cheers.

Comment: For displaying it, maybe it should just be done by default, both on the TOC and possibly on the wizard pages themselves. Now to make this available from a process: the information is currently not available, unfortunately. What would you do? Pass it to as URL parameter?

Comment: We were going to include it in the SOAP data (the form data [instance('fr-form-instance']) that we are sending to a web service, so attach an action to the next/prev buttons, set the value in the xml and send using a submission. Some sort of xxf:function('current-section') and xxf:fuction('total-sections') could be good.

Comment: Got it. It might not be entirely trivial. I created an [issue with some thoughts](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2784). Comments welcome.